# I can't get esri-leaflet to work with ReactJS --> basemapLayer of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, esri, esri-leaflet

After npm installing `esri-leaflet`, and `leaflet` packages, I get the following error

[image]

**This is my maps component:**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM , {render} from 'react-don'

import L from 'esri-leaflet'
// import L from 'leaflet'     <-- won't work as well


class Map extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){

        let element = this.refs.mapRef

        // let map = L.map(element).setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
        var map = L.map(this.refs.mapRef).setView([45.528, -122.680], 13)

        L.esri.basemapLayer("Streets").addTo(map);

        console.log("ESRI::",L.esri);

        var parks = L.esri.featureLayer({
            url: "https://services.arcgis.com/rOo16HdIMeOBI4Mb/arcgis/rest/services/Portland_Parks/FeatureServer/0",
            style: function() {
             return {
                 color: "#70ca49",
                 weight: 2
             };
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Maps page</h1>
                <div id='map' ref="mapRef" style={{height: "380px"}}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Map
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: If you use CDN links in the main.html, L is global. There is no need to import. Imports are processed by Browserify or WebPack and sometimes, have problems.

Comment: Yes I know, I tried both ways, and still have the same problem

Comment: I tried ArcGIS for an assignment with crossover. I did the assignment with the JavaScript API. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-mapview/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the `1.0.0-rc.1` version of the `leaflet` with `npm i leaflet@1.0.0-rc.1` command, `esri-leaflet` doesn't require to specify a version so it's just `npm i esri-leaflet`.Here are your requires for the component:

```
require('leaflet');
import esri from 'esri-leaflet';
```

And then use the layers via `esri`  and it should work:

```
esri.basemapLayer...
esri.featureLayer...
```

Comment: Actually you were correct, I thought I already installed the latest version, but turned out it's not. I installed leaflet as you referred, and imported ESRI as you mentioned and the maps showed up! Thank you ... I'm giving you the bounty :)

Comment: Just a final question: To set the map location I use this: `var map = L.map(this.refs.mapRef).setView([41.528, 30.680], 3)` but it throws this error: `Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)` .. why is that?